# jQuery checkbox onChange

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox with an id of activelist

I tried the following but did not seem to work (I have below in) :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#activelist :checkbox').change(function () {
    alert('changed');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id='inactivelist' value="inactivelist" />
```

Comment: I don't see where is the `#activelist` container?

Comment: It's not a container, it's a faulty selector (typo *and* space, I think).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is no need to use `:checkbox`, also replace `#activelist` with `#inactivelist`:

```
$('#inactivelist').change(function () {
    alert('changed');
 });
```

Comment: do you know what is `#activelist`?

Comment: You realise there's a typo in the `id` of his posted mark-up, right?

Answer (score 7):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    alert('changed');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a typo error :

```
$('#activelist :checkbox')...
```

Should be :

```
$('#inactivelist:checkbox')...
```